# Milkman AdMob Not supported on my platform

Tags: admob, ane

I just bought the native extension for AdMob (ANDROID ONLY) like literally 30 minutes ago, and I have an error. So I added all the ANE's (Google Play), (AdMob), and even the  API SWC, they were all inside the extensions folder. I updated my XML code for my application-app.xml.

But I'm having an error:

[SWF] com.milkmangames.extensions.AdMob - 13280 bytes after decompression
[SWF] com.milkmangames.extensions.GoogleServices - 2415 bytes after decompression
[SWF] FirstAndroidApp.swf - 2566656 bytes after decompression
[AdMobExtension] WARNING: AdMob is not supported on this platform.  running in test mode.

I was wondering if you guys could fix this....

Here is my Actionscript 3.0 code:

import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.*;
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.events.*;

AdMob.init("PRIVATE INFORMATION");
AdMob.showAd(AdMobAdType.SMART_BANNER,AdMobAlignment.CENTER,AdMobAlignment.TOP);

Here is my XML code:

http://pastebin.com/jaPwH96P

My laptop specs:

My laptop is:
Acer Aspire V5
Windows 8.1
Intel Core I5-4200 U 1.6 Ghz with Turbo boost up to 2.6 Ghz
Intel HD Graphics 4400
8GB memory
500 GB Harddrive

My Adobe air version is 15.0 (The latest)

I'm using Adobe Flash cs6; not Flash builder

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a vendor support question that should be addressed to the vendor directly. It is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Admob only works on Android or IOS so I had to test on my phone. How silly of me. No wonder it didn't work on my computer! I had to test it on my device.